# REGEXP_EXTRACT value from left between 4th and 5th underscore

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a string column that contains either 7 or 8 elements that are always separated by underscores:

```
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE_FFF_GGG_HHH
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE_FFF_GGG
```

Values between underscores can be of various length and contain other characters like + as an example

How do I extract only the value between the 4th and 5th underscore? That is, for both of these strings, I would get *EEE*?

The code I am trying to use is:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT("AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE_FFF_GGG_HHH", r'.+_.+_.+_.+_(.+)_.+_.+_.+') AS a
```

If it is the longer string (ending with HHH), I get the value EEE, but if it is the shorter string, I get null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well in the case of an input like `AAA_BBB_CCC` what output do you expect?  There is no fourth or fifth underscore here.

Comment: The column never contains an input like AAA_BBB_CCC, it always has a string which values are split either by 6 or 7 underscores.

Comment: Then `REGEXP_EXTRACT` with a capture group should be working here, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following logic using `REGEXP_EXTRACT` with a capture group should be working here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, r'^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+)'
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to split your string into an array, and select the 5th element of it (from 0)

```
WITH test AS
  (SELECT "AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE_FFF_GGG_HHH" as letter_group
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE_FFF_GGG" as letter_group)
  
 
 SELECT letter_array[OFFSET(5)] FROM (SELECT SPLIT(letter_group, "_") as letter_array FROM test) T;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. Still wondering what would be the REGEXP_EXTRACT solution one-liner solution for this.

Comment: @viiivi sorry, I suck at regexp ;)